# Android: Single Activity & Multiple Views

Tags: android

I have a very specific situation where i found that a single activity generating multiple views is the most correct approach:

- The main activity receives a code from the server (XML like) saying what it should build. That XML can contain links to other views that use similar code.

To use this, i build only one activity that decodes the code sent from the server and builds the view...

When i pass from a screen from this activity to another screen of this activity, retrieving more server-code on press of a button, it's all ok. But... when pressing back, the last view has also been altered.

I understand this, the activity being used is probably the same.. how can i avoid being the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Really stupid... I had a static variable that was accessed onResume so it messed all up...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Singleton Class which is initiated only once and retain values.